# Table View Cell Action Between View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an app that is two view controllers connected via a tab bar controller. The first view is a tableView cell and the second is several labels that are connected.

Currently my code works so that when I select a cell in the table view, it brings up the associated information from the second view controller. However, to get back to the first view controller, I currently have a back button.

How do I make it so the tab bar controller buttons don't disappear when the cell is tapped, so that I can quickly and more seamlessly jump between the two view controllers?

Relevant code for selecting a cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    x = indexPath.row
    y = indexPath.row
    z = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "seque", sender: self)
}
```

And then I call this in the viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

            xLabel.text = wordList[x]
            yLabel.text = wordDefinition[y]
            zLabel.text = wordSnippet[z]
```

Comment: add code , screenshots and elaborate

Comment: do you have a tabbarcontroller and a navigationcontroller at the same time?

Comment: @luk2302 just the tabbarcontroller I think.

Comment: What segue type are you using ? If modal change it to show

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you need to have your first VC embedded into a NavigationController and the Navigation Controller embedded into a TabBarController.

This way, when you drag a segue from your first VC to your second VC, the second VC will also be embedded into the same Navigation Controller.

And since the Navigation Controller is inside a TabBar Controller, the second VC will also be embedded into the same TabBar Controller.

You will end up with something like this:

[image]

As you can see, all VCs retain the TabBar and the Navigation Bar.

And you can do this by selecting the desired VC and then from Editor menu > Embed in.

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.